# Error en Conexion a mi modelo de Datos Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#

Tengo un proyecto que estoy migrando de dataset a Entity Framework, cree el modelo de datos en C#, cuando llamo o quiero acceder a los datos me da error de conexion, copie el app.config del modelo a los proyectos pero no logro conectarme, dejo imagen del mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sus comentarios, el nombre SIAFEntities esta en la cadena de conexion, pero marca error siempre.

Saludos

Comment: En en web.config (o app.config, o applicationconfig.json) revisa si tienes la cadena de conexión.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SIAFEntities"      connectionString="metadata=res://*/SIAFModel.csdl|res://*/SIAFModel.ssdl|res://*/SIAFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(Local);initial catalog=SIAF_TRANCIS;persist security info=True;user id=siaflgn;/>
  </connectionStrings>
Gabriel este es parte de la cadena y esta en el app.config. este archivo lo copie a las otra dos soluciones que tengo, estoy detenido debido a este error:
Saluds

Comment: Podrías poner en la pregunta todo el appconfig, o al menos la mitad que muestre la cadena de conexión.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SIAFEntities"
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/SIAFModel.csdl|res://*/SIAFModel.ssdl|res://*/SIAFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(Local);initial catalog=SIAF_TRANCIS;persist security info=True;user id=siaflgn;password=123456;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Esta es la cadena de conexion del config.app, tengo un proyecto en este 4 soluciones.

Saludos